# GSON automatically unwrap JSON array to Java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to map JSON response to a Java object. My Java class looks like this:

```
public class Response{
    private String status;
    private String message;
    ...
}
```

The JSON I'm working with is out of my control, so modifying JSON is not an option.

```
{
    "status": ["Sucess"],
    "message": ["Some Message"],
    ...
}
```

I'm using GSON to convert.

```
final Response response = new Gson().fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

Every property of objects is wrapped inside a JSON array. Terrible design, but I can't do anything about it. Is there anything in `GSON` that would automatically detect that `status` and `message` is not an array in my Java object, and thus unwrap the first entry from the JSON array?

Comment: Write your own `JsonDeserializer`

Comment: `JsonDeserializer` works for a specific type only, i need a generic one, so dont think it will work

Comment: why don't you map `status` and `message` to `String`[]` and get the first value while using them?

Comment: because there are hundreds and hundreds of fields i need to change to arrays.. im not willing to do that, it makes using those fields impractical. `getItem()[0].getSecond()[0].getThird()[0]` and so on

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the similar issue while designing an automation testing framework.

I would like to suggest you to use `ObjectMapper` which maps json key with POJO fields.

```
 public Response getResponseObject ()
    {

        Response object = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper( );
        mapper.enable( DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY );  //<-- This will do the magic to accept as an array
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        // assuming your json in data.json
        try ( InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream( ( data.json ) ) )
        {
            object = mapper.readValue( in, Response.class );
            System.out.println( ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString( object, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE ) );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            LOG.error( "Error occurred while creating Result object, cause:" + e.getMessage() );
        }
        return object;
    }
```

[read more](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), hope this helps.

Comment: does `ObjectMapper` unwrap JSON arrays in a way i need?

Comment: Yes it will, i have done it. I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: i get this error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token`

Comment: Change your field to List<String>

Comment: while this works, i did want a GSON solution. i'm actually very frustrated with `jackson` xml which is why im moving away from this garbage altogether

Comment: you want `JsonDeserializer` check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853533/how-to-unwrap-single-item-array-and-extract-value-field-into-one-simple-field)

Comment: ive looked into it. i need to write a `JsonDeserializer` for every class. i need a generic one that works for all classes. i dont know why this feature isnt already part of GSON. looks like things are more difficult than they should be